# How to return BadRequestObjectResult from Invoke method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I am developing an API which initially validates the Accept header from the https request then respond through middleware. I have added the logic to validate the Accept header in Invoke method as shown, How do I return bad request object if the result of the validation(string comparison) is false.

```
//Invoke method 
public async Task<ObjectResult> Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
   bool result = context.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString() == 
   "app/version.abc-ghi-api.v";
   if (result == true)
   {
     await  _next(context);   
   }
   ObjectResult objectResult = await 
   Error.GenerateErrorMessage("Accept header validation 
   failed", Log.Logger);
   return objectResult;  
}

//Error class
public class Error
{
    public async static Task<ObjectResult> Error(string message, logger log)
    {
       //logic for creating the payload
       return new BadRequestObjectResult(errorMessagePayload)
    }
}

//Startup class configure method
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseMiddleware<AcceptHeaderMiddleware>();
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {   
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }
     else
     {          
         app.UseHsts();
     }

     app.UseMvc();
}
```

I am expecting badObjectResult(when the validation fails) as a response but I am getting 200 OK response and blank response body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IActionResult` types are only used within the MVC pipeline. As part of that pipeline, the result objects from actions or MVC filters are then executed to create an actual response on the [`HttpResponse` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

This however means that you effectively cannot use action result objects outside of the MVC pipeline. So if you have a custom middleware, you won’t be able to use those results as they won’t be processed by the MVC pipeline (technically you *could* execute the results yourself, but I would not recommend doing that).

So instead you will have to set the result yourself. If you just want to set some (failure) status code, that is very easy to do:

```
public async Task<ObjectResult> Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    bool result = context.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString() == "app/version.abc-ghi-api.v";
    if (result)
    {
        await  _next(context);   
    }
    else
    {
        context.Result.StatusCode = 500;
    }
}
```

If you want to include a body, then it gets a bit more complicated as you now have to write to the output stream, which also means that you first have to serialize your output properly.

So instead of doing that in a custom middleware, I would suggest you to do it inside of an MVC filter. As mentioned above, [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) run as part of the MVC pipeline, so they only run with the MVC middleware. This means that you won’t be able to protect your static files that way – but usually that is not such a big deal.

In your case, since you want to authorize a client through a HTTP header, I would suggest you to create an [authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#authorization-filters):

```
public class AcceptHeaderAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool result = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"].ToString() == "app/version.abc-ghi-api.v";
        if (!result)
        {
            var result = new Error.GenerateErrorMessage("Accept header validation failed", Log.Logger);
            context.Result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

This now uses the MVC pipeline, so you *can* use `IActionResult` objects. Since you are setting a result in an authorization filter, you are also short-circuiting the remaining pipeline, so nothing will be executed afterwards. The execution will stop and immediately produce your result.

---

One final note: The [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) has a very specific use case, which is for content negotiation. That means that when you set it to some custom content type, the server is expected to return a result with such a content type. Using it for authorization purposes does not really fit here.